# Do not delete custom changes in the plugin after the update

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I have made **changes** to a WordPress plugin
And every time I update the plugin, the changes are deleted and I have to apply the changes again
How can I keep my changes? Can I write changes as a plugin? How ?

Comment: This question is too vague. What changes? Your code? Your wordpress options?

Comment: I am using a popular WordPress plugin (dokan pro) I changed some of the functions of this plugin but after updating to higher versions my changes will be deleted @jeff

Comment: When you touch code-files from the plug-in, they will overwritten. You need to create your own files and place them next to the plug-in files. The you have to use sth. like require / include to "use" your code files.

Answer (score 0):

You need to download the copy of the files which you have made the changes. After the update you need to copy the codes again.

The plugin update will replace your plugin files, because the plugin developer made the changes in their codes for add new functions of fix the bugs.